# Crossfilter transformation example

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I tried to transform the following json data with crossfilter

```
[{ Company: "Company 1",  Min: 1, Max: 5, Year: 2013 },
{ Company: "Company 1",  Min: 2, Max: 6, Year: 2014 },
{ Company: "Company 2",  Min: 3, Max: 7, Year: 2013 },
{ Company: "Company 2",  Min: 4, Max: 8, Year: 2014 }]
```

My expected result is:
First Transform

```
(Min) = [
{ key: "Company 1", 2013: 1, 2014: 2 }
{ key: "Company 2", 2013: 3, 2014: 4 }
]
```

OR

```
(Max) = [
{ key: "Company 1", 2013: 5, 2014: 6 }
{ key: "Company 2", 2013: 7, 2014: 8 }
]
```

Second Transform

```
(Min) = [
{ "Company 1": 1, "Company 2": 3, key: 2013 },
{ "Company 1": 2, "Company 2": 4, key: 2014 },
]
```

OR

```
(Max) = [
{ "Company 1": 5, "Company 2": 7, key: 2013 },
{ "Company 1": 6, "Company 2": 8, key: 2014 },
]
```

I didn't find a way to do this. Has someone a basic example for this?
Or is crossfilter.js the wrong way to do this?

Comment: If you want I could develop a function for Min, Max separately.Is it Ok.

Comment: Min and max are samples only. This could be also avg, sum or something else.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it's just a one-off transformation, then Crossfilter is probably the wrong solution.